# Should I expose AWS Credentials on github?

Tags: credentials, amazon-s3

Before you screen "No, never!", please read on :)

**Question:**
Is hard-coding IAM creds with extremely restricted permissions (only GET requests to s3) ok? I realize that there are other ways, but they all involve a good amount of work and in my head this is not much different from a public ftp server.

**Background / Project Requirements:**

- Open Source Project (eventually), so lots of different people working on and setup complexity should preferably be low
- File processing that heavily relies on `AWS.s3()` module (nodejs)
- Requests are recorded and then mocked to improve test run speed
- Different requests need to be made against the same set of files on s3 (e.g. requesting partial data, reading headers).
- New files are added automatically, existing files do not change

**Note:**
Since we need to use `AWS.s3()`, making the s3 bucket public doesn't help since authentication is always required.

Comment: So if someone doesn't like you or your project, all they need to run a lot of those GET requests to present you with a nice bill?

Comment: Fair point. However couldn't you say the same about exposing any content through on demand infrastructure?

Comment: You have much better control on your infrastructure. For example, you can detect and ban the offender relatively easily, while on S3 it is not really possible.

Comment: Right. That makes sense. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from this being a bad idea in general (see comments on question), also a bad idea because aws will restrict your account once they find out.

Resolution process is time intensive and plenty of work as you need to change all credentials on your account, no matter the permissions of the leaked creds :)